# STRAPI: Triggering a cloud function when a new collection type object is created

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, strapi

I am currently working with STRAPI (which is a headless CMS), I need to hit a cloud function whenever an object is created in a collection.

Is there any way to achieve this?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#lifecycle-hooks) for that.

```js
// ./src/api/[api-name]/content-types/[api-name]/lifecycles.js

module.exports = {
  beforeCreate(event) {
    const { data, where, select, populate } = event.params;

    // do something
  },

  afterCreate(event) {
    const { result, params } = event;

    // do something to the result;
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.Just a doubt whether I can make get/post calls to cloud function(or external APIs) from a lifecycle hook. Can we make fetch calls to any other external system?
Thanks!

Comment: Sure, use whatever library you like to make these calls. I personally use axios. These lifecycle hooks can be async.